# Badges in achievements dialog appear as if they came from the current site

Tags: bug, badges, achievements-dialog

Notifications that inform you of a received badge show an image of the badge.

This image always appears in the style of the badges from the site you are currently viewing, not the site the badge came from.

This seems incorrect.

[image: Badges appear as they would from Android SE, even the SO one]

Comment: No that's not a bug in my opinion. This will most likely just be marked as [tag:status-bydesign], so feel free to change it into a feature request. (my -1 will stay though)